# Selenium Pandas stock check

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe

I'm working on a script to import product links and check if the item is in stock or not. Currently I'm importing the CSV as a data frame through pandas then splitting the the data frame into 4 separate lists for multithreading. What would be "best practice" to re-write to the csv if the item is in stock or not?

below scrapes the site and checks if its in stock or not and should write back to the data frame with the results, but its writing yes for all the items when there are items that are out of stock. compared to the terminal output where its writing both in stock and out of stock...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import csv
import pandas as pd
import threading
import sys
import time
import os
import random

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_driver = C:\Users\~\Desktop\chromedriver.exe

def split_list(a_list):
    half = len(a_list)//2
    return a_list[:half], a_list[half:]

# :: Scrape original data from sheet
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\~\Desktop\sorted_items_1.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Sales'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Sales'])
df['Total Sales'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total Sales'])
df_filter = df.drop(df[(df['Sales'] < 4) & (df['Total Sales'] < 30)].index) # & (df['Current Price'] < 500.00)
links = [x for x in df_filter['Link']]
print(df_filter)
print('Amount of links to check:', len(links))

# :: Scrape each site for stock check
def check_stock(d,link):
    global df
    links = link
    results = []

    for i,l in enumerate(links):
        d.get(l)
        time.sleep(3)
        try:
            if d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="w1-6-_msg"]').text == 'This item is out of stock.':
                df['In Stock'] = 'No' 
                print('Item {}/{} : Out of stock'.format(i,len(links)))
            else:
                df['In Stock'] = 'Yes' 
                print('Item {}/{} : In stock'.format(i,len(links)))

        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print('Problem with item {}\n'.format(i))
            print(e,'\n')
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    list_1, list_2 = split_list(links) # initial split into 2 lists

    A, B = split_list(list_1) # split list 1 into 2 more parts
    C, D = split_list(list_2) # split list 2 into 2 more parts

    print('Searching Links',len(A),len(B),len(C),len(D))

    p1 = threading.Thread(target=check_stock, args=(webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path=chrome_driver),A,))
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=check_stock, args=(webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path=chrome_driver),B,))
    p3 = threading.Thread(target=check_stock, args=(webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path=chrome_driver),C,))
    p4 = threading.Thread(target=check_stock, args=(webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path=chrome_driver),D,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\~\PycharmProjects\~\Files\final.csv', index=False)

    print('Completed')
```

[Code output to terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fpMg.png)